# Display Single Attachment Image file size, uploaded date, resolution, file-name etc in Sidebar

Tags: metabox, attachments, sidebar, single, images

Sorry for any wrong details. I am totally new to WordPress development. I am running a photo site. On single attachment page, I want to show the details (i.e upload date, filename, size, resolution) of the attached image in the sidebar of that single attachment page. I am trying to use the following function in the single-attachment-sidebar-template.php

`<?php wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered ); ?>`

But it makes the whole sidebar invisible. I am trying to get something like post metabox in the editable interface for the image to be visible on the front in the sidebar area of the single attachment page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you post a little bit more of your code? That will help to check, why it's not working properly...

Answer (score -2):

```
filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) );
```

better you can share your site.

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you think this is an answer?

Comment: hi, if you want to show the details in single.php then you can add code in that file. if other then called to separate file.

Comment: add this code in theme single.php file 

<?php the_title();?>
Title : <?php the_title();?><br/>
Category : </strong> <?php the_category(' &bull; ') ?> <br/>
Viewed :</strong><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());?><br/>
Resolution : <?php $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full'); echo $large_image_url[1]?> x <?php echo $large_image_url[2]?>px <br/>
Tags :</strong><?php the_tags( $before = '', $sep = ', ', $after = '' );?><br/>

Comment: hello Krzysiek Dróżdż,

check here is correct ans.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's a full answer for that question. It only shows size of that image.

Comment: hello, Krzysiek Dróżdż, its working fine for my side thats why i give ans.
but its working in single post.

Comment: It is working. It just doesn't solve the problem from question. Where is the info regarding upload date or filename? I don't see it anywhere in your code...

Comment: uploaded date. Added on <?php the_date();?>
file name. <?php the_title();?>

its complete sorry i miss before.

Comment: sorry, but no... It just a list of random lines of code that you wish to work. Your post is not an answer...

Comment: @jahangir [Page View, with that code In single photo sidebar.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17tUePLpLZKe6s5Zr_r9tkK1vSBiJJIgG)
[Page View, without that code in my single_photo_sidebar.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qq7MWIbMYsea5gjNrLEDzK-JvbitDuN_)